# nix-shell error - mkdir: cannot create directory '/nix/store/...': Read-only file system

Tags: nixos

I'm using `nix-shell` to debug my package.
The configure script looks like this:

```
configurePhase = ''
  mkdir -p $out
  ...
'';
```

When running via `nix-build`, this code is OK, but when running with `nix-shell` I cannot create `$out` directory when running `configurePhase`

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/nix/store/...': Read-only file system
```

I understand why that happens, but how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `$out` points to `/nix/store/...` which is mounted as readonly.

As [Eelco Dolstra pointed](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/6769#issuecomment-123672559), there are at leasy two ways to fix this:

- Don't create `$out` in `configurePhase`, do it in `installPhase` instead.
- Set `$out` to some different value.

You can set `$out` variable with

```
nix-shell --command "export out=/tmp/foo; return"
```